# wait for several appls to finish

Tags: c++, process

I have two C++ applications:

1. *calc* - computationally intensive, reads config from a file
2. *ui* - provides user friendliness. Transforms the choices the user makes in a UI into a config, launches *calc* and when *calc* finishes, displays the results.

I would like in *ui* to launch several instances of *calc* and wait for all of them to finish, then process the results of all. The question is, how can I wait for 8 simultaneously launched processes to finish? I googled around a bit but reached no conclusion. spanwl with P_NOWAIT seemed promising, but there seems to be no easy ("built-in") way of seeing whether the process has already finished.

Any help is much appreciated, 
Daniel

Comment: What is the operating system?

Comment: Guess u r using `CreateProcess`. Use [WaitForSingleObject](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms687032%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) on the process handle produced by `CreateProcess`.

Comment: Or probably WaitForMultipleObjects in this case :)

Comment: Many thanks, your comment made me stumble upon http://mssqlwiki.com/2011/12/31/how-to-create-process-int-c-createprocess-function/ which should be exactly what I look for. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you create the processes by calling CreateProcess, you will get back a process handle that you can wait on. To wait on multiple handles at once, use [WaitForMultipleObjects](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms687025.aspx) function. This function has a limit - it can only wait for MAXIMUM_WAIT_OBJECTS (which was 64 for XP, not sure what it's in Win7) handles at a time.

Comment: Thank you. I'm facing a rather odd problem, however. When I launch the calc app using CreateProcess, the calc app behaves extremely weirdly. For example, the calc tries to open a file which does not exist. When launched from the command line, the app sees that the file does not exist. However, when launched via CreateProcess from ui, the "if ( f=fopen(...)) == NULL )" does not catch and the file is open even though it does not exist (leading to a crash). Another feat launching calc via CreateProcess is that I don't get to see any messages produces by printf() in the calc. Any ideas?

Comment: Your calc app process inherits the current working directory from the process that created it. Try using absolute path instead.

Comment: Oh, and you can pipe the stdin, stdout and stderr of that process. See lpStartupInfo parameter of CreateProcess. You can use CreatePipe function to create the necessary handles.